# Use VBScript to show properties dialog/sheet - for multiple items

Tags: vbscript

I'm trying to write a script in VBS to show the file properties dialog/sheet for multiple items. Those items will be all of the items in a parent folder (e.g. all items in W:\).

Essentially, I'm trying to get the properties dialog to show the number of files in a drive. Right-clicking on the drive and selecting Properties does not show the number of files. You would instead need to go into the first level of the drive, select all folders/files, and *then* right-click and select Properties.

I have customised some code (below) I've found on the internet to bring up the file properties dialog/sheet for either a specific folder, or a drive. I have no idea what I could further change to get the properties dialog for all files and folder of a specified drive. Perhaps getting all folders/files of the drive into an array and then working with that?

Please note I'm looking for the actual properties dialog, and not just a simple return of the total number of files (I know how to do this).

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks :)

Code:

```
dim objShell, objFSO, folParent, sParent, filTarget, sFileName, sOutput, fivVerbs, iVerb, vVerb, fvbVerb, testItemsParent, TestMappedDestination

set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject") 
set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")

const mappedDestination = "c:\"
vVerb = "P&roperties" 

sParent = objFSO.GetParentFolderName(mappedDestination) 
sFileName = objFSO.GetFileName(mappedDestination)

If Len(mappedDestination) = 3 then
    nsTarget = &H11
    TestMappedDestination = "(" & UCase(Left(mappedDestination,2)) & ")"
Else
    nsTarget = sParent
    TestMappedDestination = UCase(sFileName)
End If

set folParent = objShell.Namespace(nsTarget)

For each filTarget in folParent.Items 
If Len(mappedDestination) = 3 then
    testItemsParent = UCase(Right(filTarget,4))
Else
    testItemsParent = UCase(filTarget)
End if

If testItemsParent = TestMappedDestination then 
    Set fivVerbs = filTarget.Verbs 
    For iVerb = 0 to fivVerbs.Count - 1 
        If fivVerbs.Item(iVerb).Name = vVerb then 
            Set fvbVerb = fivVerbs.Item(iVerb) 
            fvbVerb.DoIt() 
            filTarget.InvokeVerbEx fvbVerb.Name, "" 
            Msgbox "Placeholder msgbox to keep properties dialog/sheet from disappearing on script completion"
            Exit for 
        End if 
    Next 
    Exit for 
End if 

Next
```

Comment: Bump? :( Just in case there's someone out there that sees this...